# Decrypt encrypted String with SecretKeyEntry from keystore

Tags: java

i tried a new software for my web application. I want to change the default-passwords there and want to verify that it works well. So i only see in the exported files the encrypted String. Every exports generates a different encrypted String. I know, that the passwords are encrypted by a SecretKeyEntry from a Keystore. I know, that this Key is an AES 128 Bit entry. 
I also know the password of the keystore and the key-entries.

Are there any possibilites to decrypt the encrypted Strings with a java sandbox project?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `keytool` command line if you want to check the contents quickly. Otherwise, in a java project you can use the Keystore classes:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    // get user password and file input stream
    char[] password = getPassword();

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("keyStoreName");
        ks.load(fis, password);
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
```